# How to display currently logged in user id,ip address and its OS login?

Tags: database, oracle

I want to display currently logged in user id, ip address and its OS login.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sys_context](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions150.htm#sthref1809) function to get that kind of information:

```
SQL> select sys_context('userenv', 'session_user') as curr_user
  2       , sys_context('userenv', 'ip_address')   as ip_address
  3       , sys_context('userenv', 'os_user')      as os_user
  4    from dual
  5  ;
```